# get the value from dataset using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angular2-routing

I am using droppable event  when I console the value of event its showing data in this type:-

```
 console.log('event-d--', event.target.childNodes[4]);
 this is result
 dataset:DOMStringMap {sectionvalue: "599a974a7c086869cba64435"}
```

but when I get data its showing undefined here is my code:-

```
 console.log('event-d--', event.target.childNodes[4].dataset["sectionValue"]);
```

its showing undefined and I also tried this:-

```
console.log('event-d--', event.target.childNodes[4].dataset["sectionvalue"]);
console.log('event-d--', event.target.childNodes[4].dataset.sectionvalue);
```

But no luck and here is my HTML code:-

```
   <td  *ngFor="let doctor of calendarUsers" style="width:10%; border-right: 1px solid #eee;">
    <ul id="{{doctor.id}}" class="connectedSortable">
        <li *ngFor="let calendarAppointment of calendarAppointments | filterBy: {resourceId : doctor.id}" class="ui-state-default"
         attr.data-sectionvalue="{{doctor.id}}"  ></li>
    </ul>
   </td>
```